# Read binary file from wix setup at installation step

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I`m having some trouble trying to modifying an sql script, marked in wix as Binary file.
Basically, what I want to do is read the file (binary file as it is declared), replace some values in it based on properties set in wix, and save the file, then run it as an sql script.
What I have tried so far: Getting the target directory with session.GetTargetPath("TARGETDIR"), but it returns me with wrong path, not the one where the script is initially extracted(such as a temporary folder) so i can modify it, then save it and make sure it will run the modified script.
My question is: 
HOW can I get the path of a binary file at installation step, or how can I access it via session or w/e?

To mention: I have tried declaring it as a file, and later I can not run it as an sql script, cause it requires a binary, not a file.

Thanks!

Comment: Late edit:I just need a way to get the temp folder path where the msi is extracted before it starts to execute the install sequence

Comment: You mean the [`SourceDir`-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371857(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [formatted string format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for entries in the file-table, i.e. [#filekey] to get the full path of the file. You should then be able to either set a property / CustomActionData-property and read it within a VBSScript.
Please note also the following (extract from the linked page):

```
 The value of [#filekey] remains blank and is not replaced by a path until the installer runs the CostInitialize action, FileCost action, and CostFinalize action.
```